# How to identify tags (key words) automatically from a given text?

Tags: algorithm, full-text-search, text-analysis

It should behave like [Delicious toolbar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/delicious-bookmarks/) for Firefox does; it lists possible tags to click. The effect is shown as below:

[image]

The code should be able to find key words for the text. Any good algorithm or open source project to recommend?

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2853384/how-to-identify-ideas-and-concepts-in-a-given-text), but it is a bit too general for my specific need.

Comment: OK, I think you need to be a little more specific than just "it lists possible tags to click"... delicious is a bookmarking service and the the question you referenced is for data-mining/text-mining. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: edited. I wish the question to be clearer now..

Comment: I thought that these tags are sampled from the tags that other people has already bookmarked on this URL.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you're looking for one of these answers,

- [tag generation from a text content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661778/tag-generation-from-a-text-content)
- [How to extract common / significant phrases from a series of text entries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2452982/how-to-extract-common-significant-phrases-from-a-series-of-text-entries)
- [tag generation from a small text content (such as tweets)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764116/tag-generation-from-a-small-text-content-such-as-tweets)

In a nutshell - you're looking to extract unigrams from the text that somehow represent the concepts within it - a technique to do this is called Pointwise Mutual Information, which is illustrated with an example in the first two links. Using the Python NLTK framework (which already has a bunch of these algorithms built in) might be your best starting point to work off from.

Good luck!

Comment: This is by far the most helpful answer for this question. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks! In case you found the answer useful - you might want to accept it.